# How to make the hole and bevel in the hole without effecting the geometry

Tags: modeling

I have been struggling for hours now trying to figure out a way

[image: My model]
I have made a separate object for the shape of the hole. But I don't know how to go further.

[image: Inspiration]

Comment: You may want to see [boolean modifier] with  difference selected, to cut out one object from the other.  This site BSE or the famous website which has a name that rhymes with noonoob has tutorials on the topic.  There are many examples here on BSE for you to find.  So maybe you will see some hard surface example .  You can also see face example where they shape the eye or mouth.

Comment: On the right side of this web page are suggestions... titled [Related].  You may also want to see tutorials on the site mentioned above.